# Refresh Fragment view in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentmanager

In my application I have 3 fragments in a viewPager. 
For the first fragment I would like to reload the view after a button press (basically call again the `onCreateView()`).

To get this functionality I decided to use `FragmentTransaction`, `detach()`, `attach()` and `commit()` the fragment.

In fragment I have created `SetData()` method:

```
public void setData() {
    Fragment frg = null;
    frg = mainMenu.getFragmentByPosition();
    final android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
}
```

In the activity which holds the viewPager I have `getFragmentByPosition()` method:

```
public Fragment getFragmentByPosition() {
    String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
}
```

The problem is that I get NullPointerException in `getFragmentByPosition()`

**UPDATE**

The problem is that I cannot get the reference to a currently shown fragment.

`adapter.getItem(1)` - returns `null`

`getFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0)` - returns `null`

Comment: Have you tried with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 fragments, create 3 unique strings `TAG1`, `TAG2`, `TAG3` and then add each fragment using his unique tag

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mycontainer, new MyFragment1(), TAG1).commit();
```

Then find using the same tags

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG1);
```

Comment: Does it also work this way if the fragments are in FragmentPagerAdapter?

Comment: FragmentPagerAdapter gives a fragment for a position given. getItem(1) shall always be returning your first fragment, getItem(2) the second etc. No tags at all.

Comment: The problem is that the adapter.getItem(1) have also NullPointerException.

Comment: OK, currently the NullPointerException is in SetData() method (I have changed the previous code) - getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(frag).attach(frag).commit();
frag is the fragment passed from adapter.getItem(1).